# Take input from a user and use it in a boolean function using Java?

Tags: java

I am new to programming and I am writing code for this assignment in school in which I need to have the user enter a month (first three letters), and then a year (taking in to account of leap years). This is what I have done:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter a year: ");
    int Year = input.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Enter a month (first three letters with the first"
            + " letter uppercase): ");
    String Month = input.next();

    String ThirtyOne = "Jan" + "Mar" + "May" + "Jul" + "Aug" + "Oct" + "Dec";
    String DaysThirtyOne = ThirtyOne.substring(21) + "31";

    String Thirty = "Apr" + "Jun" + "Sep" + "Nov";
    String DaysThirty = Thirty.substring(12) + "30";

    String TwentyEight = "Feb";
    String DaysTwentyEight = TwentyEight.substring(3) + "28";


    if (ThirtyOne.contains(Month)) {
        System.out.println(Month + " " + Year + " has " + DaysThirtyOne 
                + " days in it.");
    }
    if (Thirty.contains(Month)) {
        System.out.println(Month + " " + Year + " has " + DaysThirty 
                + " days in it.");
    }
    if (TwentyEight.contains(Month)) {
        System.out.println(Month + " " + Year + " has " + DaysTwentyEight 
                + " days in it.");
    }
```

My code probably doesn't look very professional and I'm sure many of you would have gone about what I've completed so far a different way but what I am having trouble with now is taking the Year input from the top and using that in an algorithm to determine if it is a leap year. I keep getting an error when I try to do it because the year is an int and NetBeans says that it can't convert int to boolean. I don't want to make another class to convert it though. What do I do to get that input from the user and use it to determine if it is a leap year? I already know that the year needs to be divisible by 4, 100, and 400.

Comment: Where are you using year variable in your code as a boolean? You are just taking user input in your int year variable.

Comment: @Moni I did just change it to boolean Year = nextBoolean(); but how do I use that variable now in a leap year algorithm?

Answer (score 1):

You can add a method before main()

```
  public static boolean isLeapYear(int year) {
  if (year % 4 != 0) {
    return false;
  } else if (year % 400 == 0) {
    return true;
  } else if (year % 100 == 0) {
    return false;
  } else {
    return true;
  }
}
```

And then check if this year is a leap Year after input user :

```
int Year = input.nextInt();
System.out.println("Is this leap year ? " + isLeapYear(Year));
```

Comment: is there a way I can do this within the main method. I just want to take the Year input and do a function for it being divisible by 4, 100, and 400.

Comment: You could write it on one line instead as:

    `System.out.print("Is this leap year ?" + Year % 4 == 0 && (Year % 100 != 0 || Year % 400 == 0));`

Comment: so ? do not forget to validate my answer